# Add Text At Location from indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on inserting text to the bottom of certain wordpress posts based on the amount of times a string occurs. I've managed to add the text to the bottom with append but instead I would like to insert at a specific location using indexOf.

here is the original text:

```
 if ($('body').hasClass("single-post")){
        var count = 0;
        var cSearch = $('body').text();
        var words = cSearch.indexOf('Words To Find')
            while (words !== -1){
            count++;
            words = cSearch.indexOf('Words To Find', words + 1);
            }
        if( count >= 2){
        $('.entry-content').append('<br><br>Sample Text');
        }
    }
```

Here is how I will get the location I want to insert before:

```
var insertLocation = cSearch.indexOf('Show what ya');
```

How can I splice the "Sample Text" into the location specified with insertLocation?

I found a bit about using polyfil for .splice but I'm not sure it works for this. Using it such as:

```
$(cSearch).splice( insertLocation, -1 ).text( "Sample Text" );
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating variables representing total matches , `indexOf()` match plus matched text `.length` , using `.slice()` to insert original text before second match , new text ti insert , followed by remainder of original text

```js
var text = $("div").text(),
  match = "Words To Find",
  txt = " Sample Text ",
  matches = 0,
  n = 0,
  // `max` : total number of `matches` before inserting `txt`
  max = 2;
while (matches < max) {
  if (text.indexOf(match, n) !== -1) {
    i = text.indexOf(match, n);
    n = i + match.length;
    ++matches
  }
}
// insert `re` after second match of `"Words To find"`
var re = text.slice(0, i + match.length) + txt;
$("div").text(re + text.slice(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div>Words To Find abc def Words To Find ghi Words To Find</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for. I guess I can work slice to do the part I need help with. The finding how many times a string occurs and the inserting the text are two separate functions and not really related. I should have been more specific, I was being lazy and reusing the variable for the content instead of just creating it again for this separate purpose.

Comment: @D.Can _"The finding how many times a string occurs and the inserting the text are two separate functions and not really related."_ `while` loop checks for matches , `i + match.length` should provide index of last character of `max` matches within `text` ; could use `.slice()` to reference this index within `text`